# Auto complete off in username textbox chrome

Tags: html

Hi i have to place auto complete off for username text box in login page the technology is .net i placed auto complete as off in asp text box but it is not working .when after login if we click on save password it is giving chrome auto fill. i don't want to give user for auto fill 
any help

Thanks

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with .NET.

Comment: Please show the relevant HTML.

Comment: Hello, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - we usually cannot help you without a code sample. Also try to tag the question with some relevant tags - this questions doesn't really ask about .NET, but HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use fake fields to avoid autocomplete to work like this :

```
<input style="display:none" type="text" name="fakeusername"/>
<input style="display:none" type="password" name="fakepassword"/>
```

Hope it will help you !

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off autocomplete using autocomplete="off"

see:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp